# Calling a second function once the first function has completed it's SKAction repeat count using Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, ios9

I have this function:

```
func midGroundlevelMovingSlow() {

    let moveLevelImage = SKAction.moveByX(-self.frame.size.width, y: 0, duration: gameSpeed)
    let replaceLevelImage = SKAction.moveByX(self.frame.size.width, y: 0, duration: 0)
    let movingAndReplacingLevelImage = SKAction.repeatAction(SKAction.sequence([moveLevelImage,replaceLevelImage]), count: 5)

    mgImage.runAction(movingAndReplacingLevelImage)
    mgImage2.runAction(movingAndReplacingLevelImage)
}
```

Once this has completed it's loop of 5, I wish to call this function:

```
func midGroundlevelMovingMedium() {

    let moveLevelImage = SKAction.moveByX(-self.frame.size.width, y: 0, duration: gameSpeed * 2)
    let replaceLevelImage = SKAction.moveByX(self.frame.size.width, y: 0, duration: 0)
    let movingAndReplacingLevelImage = SKAction.repeatAction(SKAction.sequence([moveLevelImage,replaceLevelImage]), count: 5)

    mgImage.runAction(movingAndReplacingLevelImage)
    mgImage2.runAction(movingAndReplacingLevelImage)
}
```

Can someone help me sort this out?

Thanks,

Steven

Comment: What type is mgImage?

Comment: It's an SKSprite node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SKSpriteNode has a run action function with a completion handler.

```
sprite.runAction(action: SKAction) { () -> Void in
        // call next function
    }
```

You can in that completion handler run your next method.

In your case where you want to wait for both functions to complete you could use a counter and check if both has completed before calling the next method.

something like

```
func midGroundlevelMovingSlow(completion: (()->Void)?) {

    let moveLevelImage = SKAction.moveByX(-self.frame.size.width, y: 0, duration: gameSpeed)
    let replaceLevelImage = SKAction.moveByX(self.frame.size.width, y: 0, duration: 0)
    let movingAndReplacingLevelImage = SKAction.repeatAction(SKAction.sequence([moveLevelImage,replaceLevelImage]), count: 5)

    var callCount = 2

    mgImage.runAction(movingAndReplacingLevelImage){ () -> Void in
        if --callCount == 0 {
            completion?()
        }
    }

    mgImage2.runAction(movingAndReplacingLevelImage){ () -> Void in
        if --callCount == 0 {
            completion?()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help with this, it's much appreciated.  I am getting a couple of errors though.  The first is that it is saying the action:  is extraneous and when I remove it there is an error with the --count part, any ideas?

Comment: I have a related query to this one I was wondering if you could take a look at.  I think you will be able to help.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33319558/how-do-i-do-multiple-function-calls-using-the-skspritenode-completion-handler-in